# SQL Server Log Shipping: how to change a target database to stand by?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I have added Log Shippig to SQL Server:

```
SQL server1\source_database->SQL server2\target_database
```

As I see from SSMs Report it works ok. But the target database always in "Restoring" state.
I want to change it to have a read access to the target db and made all as described here

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3600/change-the-restore-mode-of-a-secondary-sql-server-database-in-log-shipping-with-ssms/

But the target database still in Restoring mode.
What I did wrong? How to change the state and have a read access ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing:

1. Configure log shipping to use standby mode as default: (set restore_mode to 1 in msdb..log_shipping_secondary_databases on the target server)
2. Use restoring mode and manually set database to standby in the restore job

I very much prefer method #2, because it's god slow to restore every backup to standby mode if you have a lot of action in the database.

To manually use restore mode add a step in the SQL Agent Job after the restoring and run something like:

```sql
if exists(
select 1 from sys.databases where name = 'YOUR DATABASE NAME' and state_desc = 'RESTORING'
)
begin

restore database YOUR_DB_NAME with standby =  'D:\PATH_TO_STANDBY_FILE\YOUR_DB_NAME_standby.tuf'
end
```

With this method, you get faster restores and your db will be accessible as soon as the restore job is finished.

Comment: I have made as you wrote. For the start it required to restore without *.tuf file, but after it I do not see any changes in the target db. The source db has these changes and the target db is accesible.

Comment: Did you use method 1 or 2? Or what did you do exactly?
What does this returns on *target server*
select restore_mode
from msdb..log_shipping_secondary_databases
where secondary_database = 'your db'

Comment: I have used the 2.  it returns 1 ,1, i.e. as  I understand: ok. The db is accessible always. But I do not see my changes made in the source db.

Comment: Ok, i guess my instructions were a bit unclear. Method #2 means that database should be left in norecovery mode by the logshipping job, and then be manually set to standby by an extra job step.. 

So:

1. update restore_mode to 0 on target server
2. create new job step in sql server agent restore job that sets database to standby as i wrote in the original answer.
3. Run backup job on source database. 
4. If you have some copy job, run it. 
5. Then run restore job on the target database. If something is still wrong, then check the log output in SQL Server Agent for the restore job.

Comment: OK, thank you. Will do it as you described and let you know about result.